# Is there any way to print all macros that are defined when using bazel build?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

i am using bazel build to build tensorflow, and I want to know every defined macro

I tried bazel build --copt -dM , but not effective

Answer (score 0):

`--announce_rc` prints the flags that are being applied from bazelrc files and the command line including the macros.
You can run `bazel build --announce_rc <target>`

You can take help form Bazel documents [here](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--announce_rc).